# What is the spell I remember that delays ability damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage, ability-scores, content-identification

I swear I could remember a spell in Pathfinder (though possibly in 3rd Ed) which, after being cast on a character, could slow subsequent ability damaging effects by dishing out the full damage over time, say 2 points of damage a round. Can anyone point me to where I would find this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what You remember exactly but there is:

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/delay-poison/

It literally delays further poison damage ticks for as long as spell is active. Of course most types of poison deal ability damage so it fits. I don't know of any other way to slow down ability damage.